# E: Unable to locate package php5-sybase

Tags: apt, php

I am trying to install `freetds-common`, `freetds-bin`, `unixodbc`, and `php5-sybase` on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I run `sudo apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php5-sybase`, I get the following errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php5-sybase
```

How can I install this package?

Answer (score 4):

PHP5 is [**end of life**](https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php) now, and as such is no longer installable in Ubuntu 16.04 by default.

If you want to install PHP 5 packages, you're either going to have to downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04. Alternatively, if downgrading is not an option, you can try to use [ondrej](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej)'s PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-compat
sudo apt update
```

Afterwards, you should be able to install the packages you need.

However, it is important to note that PHP <s>in general</s> 5 is a security risk, and shouldn't be used if at all possible. If Bad Things happen, it's not our fault.